# Using at windows batch file edit files with vim

Tags: windows, batch-file, vim

I found very useful information on stackoverflow on how to batch edit with vim.  However I'm having problems when I want to do that for several files.  It executes the first command properly and then stops.  Here is an example:

```
vim mtc04.f90 +"1,$s/mtc03/mtc04/g" +"wq"
vim mtc04.flo +"1,$s/mtc03/mtc04/g" +"wq"
```

The idea is to replace "mtc03" by "mtc04" in a whole bunch of files, but after executing the first command it stops.  How can I make it continue.  I think this is just a basic question about windows command files rather than a vim question, but I don't know the answer, and could not find it.

Comment: is `vim` a batchfile? Then [call](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) it. If this doesn't work, [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) it.

Comment: `vim` being a third part tool, that acts line unix/Linux's vim. You should just call it, waiting for it to complete, then do the next call.

Answer (score 1):

`vim` being a windows version of the Unix `vim` editor.

You would preferably need to call it, let the batch wait for it to complete, before it starts the next edit.

```
call vim mtc04.f90 +"1,$s/mtc03/mtc04/g" +"wq"
call vim mtc04.flo +"1,$s/mtc03/mtc04/g" +"wq"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the files have the same basename, you can do the following:

```
vim mtc04.* +"bufdo! %s/mtc03/mtc04/g" +":wqall"
```